# Why no prediction value is showing using LSTM in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

Here first I wrote the model to train the LSTM  model with 4 inputs. 
Here is my code:

```
training_data= data8.iloc[:,1:] # read inputs data except datetime
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))  #scale all the input data into 0,1
train_data = sc.fit_transform(training_data)

 x_train = []
 y_train = []
   for i in range(3,len(training_data)): #predict future into 3 times
         x_train.append(train_data[i-3:i,3]) #create x_train value
         y_train.append(train_data[i,0])     #create y_train value
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train) #convert into array
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1],1)) #reshape it for LSTM model, with whole data, 4(input) , output(1)


   model = Sequential() #create LSTM model
   model.add(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None,x_train.shape[1])))
   model.add(LSTM(units=10))
   model.add(Dense(units=1))
   model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
   model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

Then I added new csv file to predict value of x1 inputs. Here is my code:

```
          dataset_test = pd.read_csv('data92.csv') #read second csv
          dataset_test = dataset_test.replace(np.nan, 0) #replace nan into 0
          inputs =dataset_test.iloc[:,1:].values #read 4 inputs

           inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,4) #reshape it

           inputs = sc.transform(inputs) #scale into 0,1
              for test in range(0,5):  #put it into range 5 not to read whole
                inputs=np.append(inputs,inputs[0])  
                inputs=inputs.reshape(-1,1)
        X_test = []
          for i in range(3,4):  #assume data will read in in this range
             X_test.append(inputs[test:i+test,:]) #create x_test


       X_test = np.array(X_test)

       X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1)) #reshape it

      new_output = model.predict(X_test) #predict the value

     inputs=np.delete(inputs,len(inputs)-1,axis=0)
     inputs=np.append(inputs,new_output)
     inputs=inputs.reshape(-1,1)   #reshpae predict value into real value

    new= dataset_test.iloc[:,1].values #read first column
    plt.plot(new)
    plt.plot(new_output)
    plt.show()
```

when I plot my graph its only showed my real value. Nothing display prediction value.
my graph:

[image]

my csv file for train model  :

[My csv files for training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JshC.png)

After training model my next csv file for test :

[new csv file for test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAf6RnHfUouUVLxR8Nqj-)

Comment: How does the data look? Try to print `new` and `new_output`.

Comment: @Solvalou  here new value =  63 104  93 177 133  70  83   & my new_output = 0.476632  only one value is showing

Comment: But this kinda makes sense since `X_test` seems to be of length one too. I guess there is something wrong with the data you want to predict. But your code is hard to understand for me, so please check for yourself first.

Comment: @Solvalou oky just give me 1 sec, I will comment all the things what I did in code, then you can understand it

Comment: @Solvalou I commented it, I hope now you can understand my code

Comment: Like I said, please check the creation of `X_test` since there is only one value appended to it. I think you made a mistake in your for loops here.

Comment: @Solvalou ya, mine x_test is coming like this ([[[0.] [0.]  [0.]]] like inputs inside of the for loop value of inputs= [[0.], [0.],   [0.]])]  I am not having any idea what I have to change in x_test code, can you help me with a code